# Python client for helm3 on microk8s

Tags: python, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I trying to install helm charts on microk8s using python client using pyhelm

```
tiller.install_release(chart.get_helm_chart(), dry_run=False, namespace='default')
```

It seems tiller is not available on microk8s helm3.

Comment: tiller was removed in helm3 and pyhelm does not work with helm3 yet https://github.com/flaper87/pyhelm/issues/84

Answer (score 1):

pyhelm doesn't have support for helm3, as edbighead mentioned, but if you're still looking for a pythonic solution to deploying helm charts, I just released an open source package called avionix that may be suited to your needs. The package was also designed with helm3 in mind, which doesn't have a tiller (part of the reason pyhelm doesn't work on helm3). You can check it out [here](https://github.com/zbrookle/avionix) or you can install it from pypi

```sh
pip install avionix
```